# Transparent background with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery fadeTo to get a transparent background of a DIV, but this also affects the content inside the DIV like text. Is there a way to only affect the background DIV and not the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$("div").animate({background: "transparent"}, 1000);
```

You'll need the [Color Animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) for that capability.

Comment: Any way doing this without a plugin?

Comment: jQuery itself doesn't include support for this, so no.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can directly download the plugin at http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

To use the plugin simply as example below:

```
$("#div").animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(73, 47, 20, 0.6)'});
```

The sample rgba value above will generate: red value = 73, green value = 47, green value = 20, and alpha value = 0.6, the less the value, the transparent.